# If the series $\sum a_n$ is convergent with positive terms, are the terms of $\sum \sin a_n$ all positive too?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

The problem I am trying to solve is:

> If the series $\sum a_n$ is convergent with positive terms does $\sum \sin a_n$ also converge?

There are numerous solutions which apply either direct comparison test or limit comparison test. Both of which require that all terms of both sequences are non-negative.

Given that all terms $ a_{n} $ are positive, how does it follow that all terms $ sin(a_{n}) $ are non negative too - Since $\sin(x)$ oscillates between $-1$ and $1$ and we don't have any information about the $a_n$ terms other than they must be decreasing.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you can prove that **there exists** $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $\sin(a_n) \geq 0$.

Indeed, because $\sum a_n$ is convergent, then $(a_n)$ tends to $0$. So because $a_n \geq 0$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $0 \leq a_n \leq \pi$ and you are done.

This is sufficient then to apply comparison test (saying that
$$\sin(a_n) \sim a_n$$

and therefore the series $\sin(a_n)$ also converges), because you don't care about the first terms when looking at the convergence of a series.

Comment: Actually, we have $\sin(x)\le x$ for all non-negative $x$ , so we do not need the asymptotic $\sin(x)$~$x$. Nevertheless (+1) for the nice proof.

Comment: @Peter You are right, thank you for the precision.